# Can I avoid repeating label restrictions in PromQL sub-queries?

Tags: prometheus, promql

Doing a query to basically give a CPU%, starts off looking like iths:

```
100 * (sum by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{mode!="idle"}[1m])))/
(sum by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{}[1m])))
```

It's already a bit of a mouthful but not too bad. But I want to limit it based on some other values, like only looking at a certain `Site` and only at `Workstation` machines (as opposed to server machines):

```
100 * (sum by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{mode!="idle", Site="xyz", machine_type="Workstation"}[1m])))/
(sum by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{Site="xyz", machine_type="Workstation"}[1m])))
```

This is prone to errors both writing, and maintaining - if we wish to tweak it it is very easy to miss the change in one clause.

Is there some way to pull out the shared parts and simplify the query?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Prometheus doesn't support the ability to specify common filters only once and then refer them in other parts of the query. But this is supported in Prometheus-compatible system - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics) via [with templates](https://play.victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs):

```
with (
 m = windows_cpu_time_total{Site="xyz", machine_type="Workstation"}
)
sum by (instance) (rate(m{mode!="idle"}[1m])) / sum by (instance) (rate(m[1m]))
```

See more details about this feature and other features of MetricsQL query language [here](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics).

Comment: Hmm,I don't think switching out our metrics solution is a real option. But it seems the answer is pretty clear.